# Not able to install mapview in Rstudio server

Tags: rstudio, rstudio-server

I am not able to install mapview in Rstudio server hosted on ubuntu. Getting the below error.Can someone please help

Error:

---

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gdtools’
* removing ‘/home/sshuser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/gdtools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gdtools’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rgdal’ is not available for package ‘gdalUtils’
* removing ‘/home/sshuser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/gdalUtils’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gdalUtils’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘units’ is not available for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/home/sshuser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/sf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘gdtools’ is not available for package ‘svglite’
* removing ‘/home/sshuser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/svglite’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘svglite’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘gdalUtils’, ‘sf’, ‘svglite’ are not available for package ‘mapview’
* removing ‘/home/sshuser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/mapview’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mapview’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install libproj-dev libgdal-dev
```

solved my issue.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered.